# Error messages for dynamic input fields using PHP

Tags: php, validation, error-handling

I have created dynamic add/remove input fields. I want to pass certain validations for it. If the user keeps it blank, a message should get displayed after submitting the form. I want PHP validations to be displayed.

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading"><center><b>Allocation of Funds</b></center></div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-5"><label>Allocation Items <b style="color:#FF0000;">*</b></label></div>
      <div class="col-md-5"><label>Amount <b style="color:#FF0000;">*</b></label></div>
      <div class="col-md-2"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-5">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="allocate_items[]" placeholder=""></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-5">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="allocate_amount[]" placeholder=""></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="add-allocation-fields"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> Add</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="fund-allocation-fields"></div>

    <p class="help-block"><i>Total amount must be equal to the goal amount.</i></p>
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var i = 0;

  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    //fadeout selected item and remove
    $(document).on('click', '#remove-allocation-fields', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $(this).parent().fadeOut(300, function() {
        $(this).parent().empty();
        return false;
      });
    });

    var rows = '<div class="fund-fields"><div class="row"><div class="col-md-5"><div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="allocate_items[]" placeholder=""></div></div><div class="col-md-5"><div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="allocate_amount[]" placeholder=""></div></div><div class="col-md-2"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="remove-allocation-fields"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span> Remove</button></div></div><div class="clear"></div></div>';

    //add input
    $('#add-allocation-fields').click(function() {
      $(rows).fadeIn("slow").appendTo('#fund-allocation-fields');
      i++;
      return false;
    });
  });
</script>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer...

```
<?php

$errors = array();

if (isset($_POST['error_test'])) {

$allocate_items = $_POST['allocate_items'];

foreach ( $allocate_items as $key => $allocate_item ) {
    if ( empty($allocate_item[$key])) {
        $errors[$key] = '<p>Allocate Item field is required</p>';
    }

}

if ( ! empty( $errors ) ) {

    foreach ($errors as $key => $value) {
            echo $value;
    }

}

}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Store one input value in a session variable or global session and compare it against required input value using a conditional statement. It's that simple.

like,

```
if(isset($_SESSION['A']) && empty(trim($_POST['RequiredField']))){
echo 'required field can\'t be empty';
}
```